# Symfony4 Extension->processConfiguration merges Parameters strangely

Tags: configuration, bundle, symfony4

I have created a Symfony Bundle -- using the DependencyInjection-mechanism that Symfony4 provides.

When my custom Extension is initialized, the provided parameters from my_extension.yaml get piped into my "load"-method as expected, as described in the SymfonyDocs ( https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/configuration.html ).

However, if I add an additional yaml-file into the designated package-scope (e.g. config/packages/dev/my_extension.yaml), these parameters end up being merged by the built-in processConfiguration() - method in a strange way:

Whereas the first config is parsed correctly and all parameter keys are kept intact, the second file is not merged as expected, but all the contained values get transformed into numeric array keys, i.e. the original parameter keys get lost on the way.

Example:

Contents of config/packages/my_extension.yaml

```
my_extension:
  parameters:
    some_attribute: "original_value1"
    some_other_attribute: "original_value2"
```

Contents of config/packages/dev/my_extension.yaml

```
my_extension:
  parameters:
    some_attribute: "new_value1"
    specific_attribute: "new_value3"
```

Results in a merged configuration array that looks like this

```
parameters:
  some_attribute: "new_value1"
  some_other_attribute: "new_value2"
  0: "new_value1"
  1: "new_value2"
  2: "new_value3"
```

while I would expect the resulting configuration to be

```
parameters:
  some_attribute: "new_value1"
  some_other_attribute: "original_value2"
  specific_attribute: "new_value3"
```

The last (correct) result is what I get if I manually merge the configs in the "load"-method of my extension like this:

```
 $mergedConfig = [];
 foreach($configs as $config) {
   $mergedConfig = array_replace_recursive($mergedConfig, $config);
 }
 $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, [$mergedConfig]);
```

However, why can't I rely on the built-in merging strategy that Symfony4 provides for this scenario? Is this a bug or did I get anything wrong about how Symfony is supposed to merge parameters from different Config-sources?